# How can I not display the same information or data twice

Tags: php, postgresql

Well let’s say that I am using multiple select on my form and the values on the DB are like on the table bellow

```
departamento|codigocurso|   curso  |codigo|disciplina|ano|diurno|laboral

------------+-----------+----------+------+----------+---+------+--------
               
        100 |       120 |Enfermagem|    1 |   numero1| 1º|    7 |      5  
        100 |       120 |Enfermagem|    1 |   numero1| 1º|    4 |      5 
        100 |      2121 | Medicina |    2 |   numero2| 1º|    7 |      8 
        100 |      2121 | Medicina |    2 |   numero2| 1º|    4 |      8 
        100 |      2121 | Medicina |    3 |   numero3| 1º|    5 |      7
```

How can I not display the same information or data twice?
Note that in the column codigocurso the 120 is repeated twice just like on the other columns, but on the column diurno the data is not repeated because of the multiple select of my form.
So it means that the whole information of the first row of our table will be displayed but the second row only the number 4 on column diurno will be displayed.
How can I make it happen?

Here is how I am getting the data from the table

```
$sql= "select distinct(ano) 
        from cursosprogramas 
        where codigocurso='$grdid' 
        order by ano asc;";
$res = @pg_query ($con, $sql);
if ($res == NULL){
    echo "Query failed.";
    exit (0);
}
for ($i=0; $i< pg_numrows ($res);$i++){
    echo '<table border=1 style="font-size:12px;" bgcolor=white width=950px><tr>';
    $ano=pg_result ($res, $i , "ano");

    $sql2="select cursosprogramas.codigo,cursosprogramas.disciplina,
                (select name 
                from professore1 p 
                where p.numero=cursosprogramas.diurno
                ) as diurno_nome,
                (select name 
                from professore1 p 
                where p.numero= cursosprogramas.laboral
                ) as laboral_nome 
            from cursosprogramas as cursosprogramas 
            where cursosprogramas.ano='$ano' 
            and cursosprogramas.codigocurso='$grdid';";
}
```

Comment: You can not - at lease with reasonable SQL. SQL returns only full rows values for columns requested. But what you ask for should be a simple task for your presentation layer. You could try a LAG function for every column in a sub-query then do a case statement column-by-column between the initial and lagged values, setting the initial value to null where they match. But I would think that would be very error prone. Just do thin in the presentation layer as it should be doen.

Comment: Hi @Belayer I have not done it before, would you please give a link of a tutorial where I can learn how to do it?

Comment: Like I said it is not something you would normally do in SQL. I've actually never seen it. Give me some time and I'll see about putting something together, but I will not guarantee success.

Comment: please post your table definition (actual DDL if possible) for each table, sample data also for each table (insert statements if possible) in particular  table professore1 and the complete expected output. and finally what is the source and value for the variable/parameter $grdid. Everything as text, **no images**. You might want to review topic [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Belayer and sorry for the late reply. Can I just edit my question or I really have to post a new one?

Comment: As long as it pertains the same issue but not completely answered then edit the question, by posting additional information. On the other hand if your requesting extending the question, for example with phases like  "Can I also ...", "now how can I ..." Then you should take two actions 1. Accept the answer provided. 2. Post a new question. Be concerned about whether it should be a new question or just extending the current, but do nor worry about. If a new question is needed the community will suggest it. Experience is a great teacher, just be willing to listen to the lessons.